# What is the different between a[i+1] and a[i]++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am not able to understand why both values are different and how does it change?

```
int a[100]

for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
cin >> a[i];

int i=20;

cout << a[i+1] << endl;
cout << a[i]++;
```

I tried to know value of both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[i+1]` that means value of `i+1`th index. which means, lets suppose if `i=20` and it has value of 50 and a[21] has value of `200` then a[i+1] means `a[i+1]=200`
so when it's about `a[i+1]` then it point to the next
and `a[i]++` that means increase 1 by `ith` index value.
so `i=20` and `a[i]=50` and `a[i]++` means `50+1` which is `51`

Answer (score 0):

```
a[i+1] you just accessing  the index of i+1  ; 
example : 
you have an array 
[4,5,6,7] and i = 0 ; 
cout<<arr[i+1] 
means than you want to print arr[0+1] which have value 5 : 
[4,5,6,7]
   ^
but when you do arr[i]++ that means that you modify the value of 4 to 
become 5 
in case if arr[i]++ simply you just add +1 to the value in arr[i]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).